# Reading website's contents into string

Tags: java, url, networking, io

Currently I'm working on a class that can be used to read the contents of the website specified by the url. I'm just beginning my adventures with `java.io` and `java.net` so I need to consult my design.

Usage:

```
TextURL url = new TextURL(urlString);
String contents = url.read();
```

My code:

```
package pl.maciejziarko.util;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public final class TextURL
{
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 10;
    private static final int ZERO = 0;
    private final byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    private final URL urlObject;

    public TextURL(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException
    {
        this.urlObject = new URL(urlString);
    }

    public String read() 
    {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            final BufferedInputStream in =
                    new BufferedInputStream(urlObject.openStream());

            int bytesRead = ZERO;

            while ((bytesRead = in.read(dataBuffer, ZERO, BUFFER_SIZE)) >= ZERO)
            {
                sb.append(new String(dataBuffer, ZERO, bytesRead));
            }
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    //Usage:
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            TextURL url = new TextURL("http://www.flickr.com/explore/interesting/7days/");
            String contents = url.read();

            if (contents != null)
                System.out.println(contents);
            else
                System.out.println("ERROR!");
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Check you the url!");
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: 
Is it a good way to achieve what I want? Are there any better solutions?

I particularly didn't like `sb.append(new String(dataBuffer, ZERO, bytesRead));` but I wasn't able to express it in a different way. Is it good to create a new String every iteration? I suppose no.

Any other weak points?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Consider using [`URLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) instead. Furthermore you might want to leverage [`IOUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to make the string reading easier too. For example:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();  // ** WRONG: should use "con.getContentType()" instead but it returns something like "text/html; charset=UTF-8" so this value must be parsed to extract the actual encoding
encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
String body = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
System.out.println(body);
```

If you don't want to use `IOUtils` I'd probably rewrite that line above something like:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
int len = 0;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
    baos.write(buf, 0, len);
}
String body = new String(baos.toByteArray(), encoding);
```

Comment: Thank you. I like URLConnection! I suppose I should use it in my project.

Comment: Be careful, `con.getContentType()` should be used instead of `con.getContentEncoding()`, but it returns something like `"text/html; charset=UTF-8"` so this value must be parsed in order to extract the actual encoding (I've added a comment on the code above to reflect this)

Comment: Awesome, i managed to get dollar price with this and some String tricks.

Comment: whats up with that number 8192 in the byte[] array?

Comment: when I use this code blok I get this error `Connection timed out: connect`

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend using a dedicated library, like [HtmlParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net):

```
Parser parser = new Parser (url);
NodeList list = parser.parse (null);
System.out.println (list.toHtml ());
```

Writing your own html parser is such a loose of time. Here is [its maven dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.htmlparser/HTMLParserProject/2.1). Look at [its JavaDoc](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html) for digging into its features.

Looking at the following sample should be convincing:

```
Parser parser = new Parser(url);
NodeList movies = parser.extractAllNodesThatMatch(
    new AndFilter(new TagNameFilter("div"),
    new HasAttributeFilter("class", "movie")));
```

Comment: Last version of HtmlParser is from 2011 and now, 2021 I cannot get its maven dependency working

Answer (score 2):

Unless this is some sort of exercise that you want to code for the sake of learning ... I would not reinvent the wheel and I would use [HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

`HttpURLConnection` provides good encapsulation mechanisms to deal with the HTTP protocol. For instance, your code doesn't work with HTTP redirections, `HttpURLConnection` would fix that for you.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `HttpURLConnection`. I need to check it. And it's also some sort of exercise :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your `InputStream` in a `InputStreamReader` and can use [it's `read()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28char%5B%5D%29) to read character data directly (note that you **should** specify the encoding when creating the `Reader`, but finding out the encoding of arbitrary URLs is non-trivial). Then simply call [`sb.append()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) with the `char[]` you just read (and the correct offset and length).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I'm sure other people will find it too.

If you don't mind an additional dependency, here's a very simple way

```
Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get().toString()
```

You'll need a [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) library, but you can quickly add it with maven/gradle and it also allows to manipulate the contents of the page and find specific nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please use these lines of codes , it will help u..

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>

        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Hello World!</h1> 






        URL uri= new URL("Your url");
        URLConnection ec = uri.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                ec.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            a.append(inputLine);
        in.close();

        out.println(a.toString());
```

Comment: Why is HTML code mixed with Java code here? Also, the HTML is lacking closing tags for `<body>` and `<html>`.