# HTTPRequest Get Data in Java

Tags: java, httprequest

I would like to do an HTTPRequest in Java and then get the data from the server (it's not a webpage the data come from a database).
I try this but the getData doesn't work.
Do you know how I can get the Data?

```
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("http://ip-ad.com");
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    System.out.println("Request method is " + httpCon.getData());
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can get the response body of the web request as an [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) with:

```
httpCon.getInputStream();
```

From there it depends on what the format of the response data is. If it's XML then pass it to a library to parse XML. If you want to read it into a `String` see: [Reading website's contents into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867975/reading-websites-contents-into-string/5868033#5868033). Here's an example of writing it to a local file:

```
InputStream in = httpCon.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("file.dat");
out = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
int len = 0;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
}
out.close();
```

Comment: the response data is in byte.
when I did the getInputStream() I have this answer : Request method is sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@83cc67. If I try the code that you give nothing is on the file

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://jersey.java.net/ .

It's a simple lib for your needs.